# Firefox downscaled image quality problem

Tags: image, firefox

I have an image 640 x 800.  It is downscaled by html attributes width and height  to 90 x 113.
It renders well in most of the browser apart from Firefox.

Here is an example:
http://arturito.net/2010/11/22/firefox-image-downscale-rendering-problem/

I know I can rescale it and have 2 copies of the same image in 640 x 800 and 90 x 113.
But I was wondering if there is any way yo fix it without having multiple copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This turned out not to be an answer, unfortunately, but I'm keeping it for the info:

This seems to be a platform-dependent problem. Firefox 8 on Mac OS X is using a good downscaling algorithm. Here is a screenshot from your sample page:

[image: OS X]

But on Windows 7, it looks jagged:

[image: Windows 7]

Comment: That is weird. I'm using FF 8.0.1 and it still appears to have the same problem.

Comment: Tried it again with Windows -- turns out the scaling algorithm depends on the OS. :( I've updated the (non-)answer.

Answer (score -2):

You missed the point. The purpose of thumbnails is to show as much information in one page as you can and make page load faster. If you use full-size images downscaled by browser your page would be loaded significantly slower and consume much more traffic while user may not even interested in most of the bigger images.

Just spent some time on image resizing.

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware of what you mentioned. My web designer applies various js effects to images and as a result he displays 1 image 3 times on the same page so loading 1 image is enough.Yes, I can make a thumbnail but next day my client is going to say that the thumbnails should be a bit smaller.Downloading hundreds of thousands of images from the server to run a batch in photoshop or even with a small script on the server - no thanks :) The question was: Why Firefox is the only browser that is not smoothing the image when downscaled in html and how to fix it? :)